# How to get "PluginProfiler.Solution.zip" - Plugin Registration Tool - Profiler

Tags: debugging, plugins, dynamics-crm, dataverse

I face problem that drives me nuts, and I cannot find a solution anywhere. Also it seems many people faced this problem, and asked in several "more expert" forums like "community.dynamics.com" ([for example here](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/164896/i-am-not-able-to-install-profiler)) or on sites of MIcrosoft MVPs like Andrew Butenko [enter link description here](https://butenko2.rssing.com/chan-10884609/all_p267.html)) and several other places.

The problem is: While developing Plugins for Dataverse, we use a tool called "Plugin Regustration Tool" to bring those plugin to the cloud:
[image]
And inside this tool we usually use a tool called "Profiler" to debug what is happening, as the plugin runs in the background, and you have no chance seeing what is going wrong in the GUI.
However, when I want to install it, I get an error:
[image]
Official documentation of Microsoft does not mention this as they do only cover the "happy" path.
Does anyone know how to get this tool working. I am searching now for hours without even a hint where to start. Also the file is nowhere to be downloaded, otherwise I would have done so as suggested by the error message:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to locate the "PluginProfiler.Solution.zip" file. Make sure that it is in the same directory as the PluginProfiler.Library.dll assembly.
> bei PluginProfiler.Library.ProfilerManagementUtility.LoadSolutionFile(String prtPath)
> bei PluginProfiler.Library.ProfilerManagementUtility.ImportSolutionAsyncAndWait(CrmServiceClient service, String prtpath, Boolean publishWorkflows, Boolean overwriteUnmanagedCustomizations, Int32 sleepInterval, Int32 asyncWaitTimeout)
> bei PluginProfiler.Library.ProfilerManagementUtility.RetrieveOrCreateProfilerPluginType(CrmServiceClient service, String prtpath)
> bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Libraries.OrganizationHelper.InstallProfiler(CrmOrganization org, String prtPath)
> bei Microsoft.Crm.Tools.PluginRegistration.OrganizationControlViewModel.<>c__DisplayClass302_0.<InstallProfiler_Clicked>b__2(Object o, DoWorkEventArgs e)

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: the solution zip file is inside the nuget package (the one you download to install PRT) and it should be beside the exe file you launch to run PRT. try to download the file again and "unblock" the file (right properties) before unzipping it

Answer (score 5):

In starting shortcut, "Start in" section just copy paste path to exe file, for example: C:\Users<UserName>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\PowerPlatform\PRT\9.1.0.155\tools

And run as Administrator.

This must fix the problem.

Comment: This did it for me! Thank you very much, I have already up-voted the answer

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error. I restarted Plugin Registration Tool as administrator. After it, Profiler was installed successfully.